# Google maps API not working on my site

Tags: api, google-maps

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



var simplerweb = new google.maps.LatLng(55.977046,-3.197118);
var marker;
var map;






      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.977046,-3.197118),  
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoom: 15,
           scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false, 
    draggable: false,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: andrewmorris,
    icon: 'http://www.andrewsmorris.co.uk/images/point.png' 
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
}





function toggleBounce() {

  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}


    </script>
```

So I can't figure out why this isn't working on my new site, works fine on my old site.

I dumped in a div called map_canvas

It SHOULD work, right?
Google maps API set up to allow referrals from that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine as long as you have the correct key.

Did you double check that you are calling **initialize()** within your html body like

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
```

Also the link to your marker image is dead.

Comment: Ah yes, the onload call was what I was missing!

Thanks!